# How would I show that there are no onto homomorphisms from Q8 to Z4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I have to show that there are no onto homomorphisms from **_ to _**, including Q8 to Z4. 
How would I show that? Also can someone explain what onto means again, my teacher didn't explain it well to me.

Comment: Onto means surjective: a function $\,f:A\to B\,$ is *onto* $\,B\,$ if $\forall\,b\in B\,\,\exists\,a\in A\,\,s.t.\,f(a)=b\,$

Comment: Presumably (from the tag, among other hints) it's a group homomorphism at issue.  What is the order of a generator of cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Answer (score 3):

We can put

$$Q_8=\{1,-1,i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}\;\;,\;\;\Bbb Z_4:=\{0,1,2,3\}$$

Suppose we have a group epimorphism

$$f:Q_8\to \Bbb Z_4\Longrightarrow Q_8/\ker f\cong\Bbb Z_4$$

But then $\,|\ker f|=2\,$ and the only subgroup of order $\,2\,$ in $\,Q_8\,$ is its center $\,\{1,-1\}\,$ , so

$\,Q_8/\{1,-1\}\cong\Bbb Z_4\,$. But this is impossible since for any $\,q\in Q_8\setminus\{1,-1\}\,$ we have that

$\,q^2=-1\in\{1,-1\} \Longrightarrow Q_8/\{1,-1\}\,$ is a $\,2-\,$elementary group (=a group where every element

squared equals the unit) and, thus, it cannot be cyclic of order four.

**Added:** We can shorten the above noting that since  $\{1,-1\}=Z(Q_8)\,$ , and since no group modulo its center can be cyclic non-trivial, then we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you do it by contradiction.  So suppose $f:Q_8\to Z_4$ is an onto homomorphism, and pick $a\in Q_8$ where $f(a)=1$.  Then $f(a)+f(a)=2\not=0$, but $f(a)+f(a)=f(a*a)$ since it's a homomorphism, and $a*a=1$ for any $a\in Q_8$.  We know that $f(1)=0$ for any homomorphism, so $2=f(1)=0$, and we have a contradiction.

Comment: How come $\,a\cdot a=1\,$ in $\,Q_8\,$?